# C# async await and threadpool

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I understand that when using async and await on a method called on the UI thread that the UI thread can be freed to do other work while awaiting some IO to complete.
If I use the async await on a method called by a  threadpool thread what happens to the that threadpool thread
while the IO completes? Is it returned to the pool? When the IO is completed what thread completes the method in this latter case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I use the async await on a method called by a threadpool thread what happens to the that threadpool thread while the IO completes? Is it returned to the pool?

Yes, the thread pool thread is returned to the thread pool.

> When the IO is completed what thread completes the method in this latter case?

By default, `await` will capture a current "context", and use that to resume the `async` method when the `await` completes. This "context" is `SynchronizationContext.Current` unless it is `null`, in which case the "context" is `TaskScheduler.Current`.

In the UI case, there's a UI `SynchronizationContext` that causes the `async` method to resume executing on the UI thread. In the thread pool case, `SynchronizationContext.Current` is `null`, and `TaskScheduler.Current` is the thread pool task scheduler. So, the `async` method is resumed on a thread pool thread (any arbitrary thread, not necessarily the same thread).

If you want more information on this behavior, I have an [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that you may find helpful.

Answer (score 4):

In that case, the continuation executes on any available thread-pool thread.

In theory it's up to the awaitable to schedule the continuation appropriately, but generally an awaitable captures the current `SynchronizationContext` when the async method passes in the continuation, and uses that synchronization context to schedule the continuation when the awaitable has completed. (Module `ConfigureAwait` calls etc.)

In the case of the thread pool, there *is* no synchronization context, so the continuation is just scheduled on any thread pool thread. (The same is true on a console app's main thread - or basically any thread where a synchronization context hasn't been set.)